# How can I specify local gradle.properties per project?

Tags: java, gradle

`gradle.properties` file is usually included in version control so all contributors can have a consistent environment, so you cannot store user-defined properties in them, and user-defined properties are applied to all projects at the same time. I want to set `org.gradle.java.home` property for projects incompatible with my default JDK, but I can't use project-level `gradle.properties` because path to JDK is not the same on different machines and I only want the JDK path to be changed for specific projects, not all of them.

Is there a convenient way to specify local Gradle properties for a single project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible solution:

1. Define an alias for custom JDK, e.g.: `jdk-8`, `jdk-11`
2. All contributors should specify paths to those JDK via build environment (any way from [Gradle Docs](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html)).
   For example:

```
// file ~/.gradle/gradle.properties
jdk-8=/path/to/jdk8
jdk-11=/path/to/jdk11
```

`jdk-8` and `jdk-11` will be resolved as properties by Gradle in any build.

3. Configure `javaCompile` task for specific projects in root `build.gradle.kts`:

```kotlin
fun Project.setupCustomJdk(jdkAlias: String) {
    findProperty(jdkAlias)?.toString()?.trim()?.let { customJdkPath ->
        tasks.withType<JavaCompile> {
            options.isFork = true
            options.forkOptions.javaHome = File(customJdkPath)
            logger.info("Task javaCompile using JDK from $customJdkPath")
        }
    } ?: logger.warn("Unknown property '$jdkAlias'")
}

project(":app").setupCustomJdk("jdk-11")
project(":lib").setupCustomJdk("jdk-8")
```